# Voyager and Jetstream: Login to Admin Panel leads to Dashboard Page

Tags: laravel, voyager, laravel-jetstream, laravel-9

I just started my first Laravel project and try to combine Jetstream Authentification with Voyager Admin Panel.

First of all, I installed Jetstream on a fresh Laravel installation and it worked so far:

Afterwards, I tried to add Voyager to generate the CRUDs for my website and added a new user with
`php artisan voyager:admin your@email.com --create`

But whenever I tried to login through the url "../admin", I was redirected to "../dashboard" from Jetstream.

Even if I reentered "../admin" as URL, I was redirected. As long as I was logged in, I cannot enter the Voyager Backend.

So I guess it's some kind of routing / middleware issue, but I cannot find out which issue it is.

Within the web.php Routing file, there's only the basic stuff:

```html
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');


Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});
```

Not sure if that's relevant, but my IDE recognizes Voyager:: as unknown class, even it works the same way on a different Laravel installation.

But from the look of it, I expected the Route::middleware() to redirect a logged in person which types the url "../dashboard" to the Dashboard view, but nothing more. Removing this Route also didnt help the problem, so I guess I was wrong.

But beside this, only the pure Voyager Routes are left, so I'm not sure where else I can look to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom responses on `app/Http/Responses` directory.

just make new responses called **LoginResponse**

then use this code

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Responses;
 
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse as LoginResponseContract;
 
class LoginResponse implements LoginResponseContract
{
    /**
     * @param  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        $home = auth()->user()->is_admin ? '/admin' : '/dashboard';
 
        return redirect()->intended($home);
    }
}
```

Then, bind your **LoginResponse** in **FortifyServiceProvider**

You can use this code

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
// ...
use App\Http\Responses\LoginResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse as LoginResponseContract;
class FortifyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // ...
        $this->app->singleton(LoginResponseContract::class, LoginResponse::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried as you suggested and added the new Response (didnt have any responses yet, so I created the folder and added the file as you suggested) and added the line of code to bind the Response in the end of the boot() method of the FortifyVersiveProvider. Didnt help yet. I also played around with this within the Auth and the Jetstream ServiceProvider, but still the same: As soon as I'm logged in, I get redirected from "/admin" to "/dashboard"

Comment: try to edit redirects in `config/fortify.php` file

Answer (score 0):

i know that it to late but for other users who had the same problem.

1. first i installed jetstream
2. int .env file APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
3. i installed voyager with dummy data
4. i added manualy in table user_roles  this ligne ( the admin )

```
INSERT INTO `user_roles` (`user_id`, `role_id`) VALUES ('1', '1');
```

and it work
you can see this video i found in youtube i think it will help you .

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDYZx5uIwmQ